# Accessing Foreign Security Principals

Tags: active-directory, security-identifier

Searching for the user `michael@mycontoso.com` with the objectSid `S-1-5-21-1234567890-123465789-123456789-123456`, I only find a Foreign Security Principal `CN=S-1-5-21-1234567890-123465789-123456789-123456,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=contoso,DC=com`.
That foreign security principal does not contain the properties I have to read, so I guess I have to access the "Home AD" of that FSP.

Does a FSP have a property that always contains the LDAP path of the user object?
Is there a standardized/recommended way how to access the Home AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly FSP don't contain the LDAP path of the referenced object.
(if it contain one, then it needs to be replicated once the object is rename/moved)

There seems no easy way to get back the containing AD using the SID from foreign forest.
If in local forest you may do it by binding to `LDAP://<SID=S-1-xxxxx>`.

A not-so-easy way is to build a **domain SID to domain map**.
Walk through each domain in trusted forests and build the map using the script here (the "The Script Solution" section).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-sid-walker-texas-ranger-part-3-exporting-domain-sids-and-trusts

SID of security principals are in the form of `<domain SID>-<RID>`.
e.g. domain SID of `S-1-5-21-1234567890-123465789-123456789-123456` is `S-1-5-21-1234567890-123465789-123456789`.

By extracting the domain SID (if in .NET you can do it by using `SecurityIdentifier` class and the `AccountDomainSid` property) and the map then you can find out the containing domain.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to retrieve the [msDS-PrincipalName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/232b83b9-f83e-4a51-b147-cf18252ffa50):

```
ldapsearch <options> -b "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=contoso,DC=com" "CN=S-1-5-21-1234567890-123465789-123456789-123456" msDS-PrincipalName
```

> FOO\michael@mycontoso.com

---

Otherwise, the approach is as https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038494/10408280 describes:

1. Retrieve Domain identifier from first part of SID
2. Perform a lookup against that domain for the SID of the user or by sAMAccountName