# SQL with Active Directory and nested groups/users

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory, openquery

i have one AD group that contains 5 users. 3 of the users are from the `Domain1` and 2 are from a trusted `Domain2`

i have a problem getting the users from `domain2` after i read out what users have access to what groups.

I'm using openquery to adsi.  (**The domain and servers are 2008 R2**)

This is an expansion of this topic

[Query AD Group Membership Recursively Through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914698/query-ad-group-membership-recursively-through-sql/27069902?noredirect=1#comment42653478_27069902)

**Update**
This is the query but im getting **error**:

```
select samAccountName,distinguishedName 
            FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'
                SELECT samAccountName,distinguishedName 
                FROM ''LDAP://domain/DC=...,DC=....,DC=....''
                WHERE 
                    objectCategory=''user'' AND
                    memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:= ''CN=..,OU=..,DC=...,DC=....,DC=....'' ')
```

This is my query that **workes** but im not getting the nested groups OR users from other domain.

```
select samAccountName,distinguishedName 
            FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'
                SELECT samAccountName,distinguishedName 
                FROM ''LDAP://domain/DC=...,DC=....,DC=....''
                WHERE 
                    objectCategory=''user'' AND
                    memberof= ''CN=..,OU=..,DC=...,DC=....,DC=....'' ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No knowledge on openquery to adsi. Only some comments:

- On second search statement, should use memberOf instead of member
- FSPs are used to represent security principal from foreign forest. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223700.aspx.
  The only hint to get back the user/group from FSP is the SID in objectSID attribute. But there seems no easy way to do this. See [Accessing Foreign Security Principals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011350/accessing-foreign-security-principals/27038494#27038494)
- You can only get direct member or containing group using member and memberOf attribute but not nested one
- Group members due to primary group are not listed in member and memberOf at all.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, according to your link [Query AD Group Membership Recursively Through SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914698/query-ad-group-membership-recursively-through-sql/), 
the following should work:

```
SELECT samAccountName,distinguishedName
    FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, '<LDAP://domain/DC=...,DC=....,DC=....>;
    (&(objectCategory=user)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=..,OU=..,DC=...,DC=....,DC=....));samAccountName, distinguishedName;subtree');
```

Also, please check the functional level according to:

http://www.technipages.com/active-directory-how-to-check-domain-and-forest-functional-level

The ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=" syntax requires functional level of 2008 R2.

Comment: Update

im getting a error when i try using this.

FROM ''LDAP://DC=..,DC=..

WHERE ObjectClass = ''user'' and memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.1.4.1941:=''CN=...,OU=...,DC=..,DC=...'' ')

 

i founde that using

:1.2.840.113556.1.1.4.1941: i will get nested groups and users that are from other domains but im not getting ths syntax to work?..

Comment: :1.2.840.113556.1.1.4.1941: (the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN matching rule) requires domain/forest functional level of 2008 R2 (forgot domain or forest). Does your forest/domain support that?

Comment: Your update works with "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941" however in the domain im searching the forest/domain is only W2K3 and that can be the reason why i can not see nested groups or users from other domain. thank i will mark your post.

Comment: I got this almost to work now.
do anyone know how i can use varible in this?

SELECT samAccountName,distinguishedName
    FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, '<LDAP://domain/DC=...,DC=....,DC=....>;
    (&(objectCategory=user)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN='+@varible+',OU=..,DC=...,DC=....,DC=....));samAccountName, distinguishedName;subtree');

the varible @varible get a error in the first + i think i might need alot of ('''''')??

Comment: According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx). OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments. You may need to compose the SQL statement into a string first, and then execute it.